# How to create a sticky div element within the container but outside current row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a quick fix here, How do I make the element with sticky class actually sticky within the container but outside it's parent row as well. Can anyone suggest me any quick fixes with HTML css and javascript? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Sticky Element</title>
 <style>
  .sticky{
   position: sticky;
   top: 120px;
   height: 200vh;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="sticky">
     <h1>Sticky element</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `position: fixed;`

Comment: @DanMullin I could use fixed but it shouldn't interrupt the elements outside the container, it should apply only to this container, there are other containers as well.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @Anton It should be sticky or fixed within the height of the container

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` is working for `sticky`, but `sticky` must be under the parent element (so in your case it must be exactly inside the `container`).

```css
.row {
  background: #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}

.row>div {
  padding: 40px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    <h1>Sticky element</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      Cell 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Cell 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      Cell 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Cell 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      Cell 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment if something is not correct.

Comment: the sticky element should be inside any of the column like ; let's put it in place of cell 3  and work as a sticky element within the container

Comment: @Rohan It seems I do not understand what you are trying to receive =( What does "sticky" means to you? Keep its position? But all cells keep their positions in container... I'm confused